# How do I prevent my java GUI buttons from shrinking (GIF included)?

Tags: java, swing

I made a GIF of my situation:

[image]

Forgive the speed of it, I made it too fast

I thought that there was a function like repaint() or such? Is there a way to keep the buttons *always* fixed?

Here's where I add Buttons:

```
guiFrame.add(but2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);        
guiFrame.add(but, BorderLayout.CENTER);     
guiFrame.add(but3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);          
guiFrame.add(combo2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
guiFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Here's [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/C9Xyn/), alternatively [here](http://snipt.org/embed/BagY0)

thanks

Comment: what action causes the buttons to shrink? Or does this behaviour appear randomly?

Comment: Don't use a border layout.

Comment: Well that's a good question. Not sure, but I don't believe its random

Comment: @mikeTheLiar- thank you, I will try this. bpxlayout work I believe?

Comment: Post your source, there is sth. messed up with your LayoutMgrs.

Answer (score 4):

1. Put your JTextArea inside a `JScrollPane` and add the scroll pane to your frame's content pane:

   ```
   textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
   getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ```
2. Put your three buttons inside another `JPanel`: `buttonPanel` with suitable [`layout manager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). Add this `buttonPanel` to the frame's content pane with `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`

   ```
   getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   ```

Comment: @Adel, you are welcome. No,need to call me a *sir*. I am a learner too :)

Comment: @Adel, forgot to mention, not sure whither you already no this, but do you mind checking [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to know how to use this site?

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that there was a function like repaint() or such? Is there a
>   way to keep the buttons always fixed?

- everything depends of used `LayoutManager`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, caused a.m. issue
- put floating `JComponent` to `JScrollPane`